# Parse Pandas Return As List

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I run the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, columns = ['DeviceNumber','DeviceAddress','DeviceCity','DeviceState','StoreNumber','StoreName','DeviceConnect','Keys'])
df.index.name = 'ID'

def srch_knums(knum_search):
    get_knums = df.loc[df['DeviceNumber'] == knum_search]
    return get_knums

test = srch_knums(int(13))
print(test)
```

The output is as follows:

```
DeviceNumber DeviceAddress DeviceCity DeviceState StoreNumber StoreName DeviceConnect Keys ID
12     13 135 Sesame Street  Imaginary   AZ         410        Verizon     Here        On Sit
```

e

btw, that looks prettier in terminal... haha

What I want to do is take the value test and use various aspects of it, i.e. print it in specific parts of a gui that I am creating. The question is, what is the syntax for accessing the various list values of test? TBH I would rather change the labels when I am presenting it in a gui, and want to know how to do that, for example, take test[0], which should be the value for device number (13), and be able to assign it to a variable. IE, make a label which says "kiosk number" and then prints a variable assigned test[0] beside it, etc. as I would rather format it myself than the weird printout from the return.

Answer (score 0):

If you want return scalar values, first match by testing column `col1` and output of column `col2` then `loc` is necessary, also is added `next` with `iter` for return default value if no match:

```
def srch_knums(col1, knum_search, col2):
    return next(iter(df.loc[df[col1] == knum_search, col2]), 'no match')

test = srch_knums('DeviceNumber', int(13), 'StoreNumber')
print (test)
410
```

If want list:

```
def srch_knums(col1, knum_search, col2):
    return df.loc[df[col1] == knum_search, col2].tolist()

test = srch_knums('DeviceNumber', int(13), 'StoreNumber')
print (test)
[410]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
get_knums = df.loc[df['DeviceNumber'] == knum_search]
```

to

```
get_knums = df[df['DeviceNumber'] == knum_search]
```

you don't need to use loc.